# Changing the Selected value of Select Menu Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have created a form and have stored the values selected by the user in a database.
But now if the user wants to edit his form, i need to reload the form with the previous values.I am using JQUERY MOBILE

I retrieved his previous values from the database but now i am having a problem with loading the values in a select Menu.Can anyone help me ?

I have used the following code :-

```
     var nameVar = (dataset.item(id)['name']);  // Getting the name from the database
     $('#StateName').val(nameVar);                   // StateName is the id  
     $('#StateName').selectmenu('refresh', true);    // Refreshing the Select Menu
```

But even after the execution of the above code nothing is reflected in the select Menu
Is something Wrong in Code or am i missing something ?

Comment: Can you post your full code including XHTML?

Answer (score 10):

Instead of value you need to append the option:

```
var nameVar = (dataset.item(id)['name']);
$('#StateName').append('<option value="'+nameVar+'" selected="selected">'+nameVar+'</option>');                     
$('#StateName').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Or if you have the Select Options already and just need to select the option, try this:

```
var nameVar = (dataset.item(id)['name']);
$('#StateName option[value='+nameVar+']').attr('selected', 'selected');
$('#StateName').selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

More on Select Menu for jQM 1.0 here:

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/forms/selects/