# UPDATED Not able to set default value for radio type and selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have checked this link [Set radio button 'checked' in jquery based on ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121785/set-radio-button-checked-in-jquery-based-on-id) However, seems not very suitable for me. This is my code

```
<label for="basic" class="basic">Gender:</label>
<fieldset data-type="horizontal" data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-1" value="Male" checked="checked" />
    <label for="radio-mini-1">Male</label>

    <input type="radio" name="gender" id="radio-mini-3" value="Female"  />
    <label for="radio-mini-3">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

and

```
<label for="select-choice-min" class="select">Living Place:</label>
<select name="select-choice-min" id="livingPlace" data-mini="true">
    <optgroup label="AAA">
    <option value="123">123</option>
    <option value="456">456</option>
    </optgroup>

    <optgroup label="BBB">
    <option value="789">789</option>
    <option value="246">246</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

May I ask how to set the default value? Thanks.

My json return is something like this:

```
[{"data":{"id":"8","livingPlace":"789","gender":"Female"}}]
```

**UPDATED**
For the living Place, I found that  when I use `$("#livingPlace").val(data[0].data.livingPlace);` it can actually get the value in the selector, when I click the selector, it can  show me the correct value, however, when the page is loaded, without clicking the selector, it just show the first value in the selector, i.e 123 in the example above

```
        $.getJSON('http://mydomain.com/getmyDetail.php?user_name='+localUsername+'&role='+localRole+'&jsoncallback=?', function(data) { // the javascripts are located here

        $('#livingPlace').val(data[0].data.livingPlace).find('[value="' + data[0].data.livingPlace + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');}
```

I did in this way, is there any problem?

Comment: When you say "set default value" do you really mean "set which radio button is selected? Your code `$("input[name=gender]:checked").val(data[0].data.gender)` is going to set the `value` attribute of the radio that is already selected...

Comment: yes, but from the json string, the gender should be female. i expected that when the form is opened, it can able to set the gender as female.  actually, should I delete the checked="checked" in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting select is just like input with jQuery:

```
$('#livingPlace').val(789); // select menu is easy
```

Your radio buttons are a little more verbose:

```
$('input[name="gender"][value="Female"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Let me explain that long selector.

input - looks for an <input> tag

[name="gender"] - looks for tags with an attribute "name" set to "gender"- this grabs both radio buttons.

[value="Female"] - This is where we narrow down to the radio button with a value of Female.

After selecting the 'female' radio button, we set the "checked" attribute to "checked". We could also set it to true. Um, the browser automatically unchecks the other radio buttons.

Put with your data, here is one solution:
http://jsfiddle.net/hRqZP/1/

```
var json = '[{"data":{"id":"8","livingPlace":"789","gender":"Female"}}]';
var data = JSON.parse(json)[0].data; // get 'data' out of json.
$('#livingPlace').val(data.livingPlace); // select menu is easy
$('input[name="gender"][value="' +
      data.gender +
      '"]'
 ).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Edit: I don't know what browser you are using, but I noticed that val() didn't set "selected=selected" on the option. In Chrome it displayed the correct value, though.
Anyway, I updated it so that it sets selected=selected, too:
http://jsfiddle.net/hRqZP/2/

```
var json = '[{"data":{"id":"8","livingPlace":"789","gender":"Female"}}]';
var data = JSON.parse(json)[0].data; // get 'data' out of json.
$('#livingPlace').
    val(data.livingPlace).
    find('[value="' + data.livingPlace + '"]').
        attr('selected', 'selected');
$('input[name="gender"][value="' +
      data.gender +
      '"]'
 ).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Edit: For jQuery.mobile the select menu may need to refresh:

```
$('#livingPlace').
    val(data.livingPlace).
    find('[value="' + data.livingPlace + '"]').
        attr('selected', 'selected').
    end().
    selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: $("#livingPlace").val(data[0].data.livingPlace);  this seems not work  $('input[name="gender"][value="Female"]').attr('checked', 'checked');  also not work, it even not able to load the page

Comment: if I remove checked="checked"  in the HTML, the page can be loaded. however, no option is selected

EDITED: it should be not able to load the page if i use $('input[name="gender"][value=data[0].data.gender]').attr('checked', 'checked');

Comment: I added a JS fiddle and an example of using it with your JSON. ;)

Comment: Could I ask a question?    $("#emailField").val(data[0].data.email);
   $("#livingPlace").val(data[0].data.livingPlace);
for the first line, I can able to get the email, why I cannot get the livingPlace by the second line?>

Comment: @HUNG What is the value when you try to alert(data[0].data.livingPlace)? And is the html you posted exactly the same as what you are currently testing?

Comment: Okay, try it now that I edited and added a hard change to the 'selected' attribute for the option with the right value.

Comment: @HUNG What is shown when you do:
alert(data[0].data.livingPlace);
And is there an option in the select menu with that value?

Comment: it alerts 789...yes, option value and the caption are the same

Comment: @HUNG Does this fiddle work for you? If not, what browser are you using? http://jsfiddle.net/hRqZP/2/

Comment: found that it does not work in jQuery Mobile 1.3.0b1 in the fiddle

Comment: @HUNG I had no idea you were using jQuery mobile. Take a look at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309886/changing-the-selected-value-of-select-menu-jquery-mobile
We seem to be missing .selectmenu('refresh',true); which seems special for jQuery.mobile.